# WPF Multibinding string format date

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to combine 2 fields of information in my grid by using a Multibinding, the multibinding is working fine but I'm having problems when I try to start formating 1 of the fields which is a date in this binding.

The 2 fields are Users Initials i.e. EGJ and the entry date hoping to achieve a combined field looking like "EGJ - 01/01/2011"

Below is where I'm with my existing XAML

```
<tk:DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
  <MultiBinding StringFormat=" {0} - {}{1:dd/MM/yyyy}">
    <Binding Path="UserInitials" />
    <Binding Path="EntryDate" />
  </MultiBinding>
</tk:DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
```

Any help or pointers are most appreciated

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Couldn't see the wood for the trees

Simply removing the empty braces solved my problem.

```
<tk:DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
  <MultiBinding StringFormat=" {0} - {1:dd/MM/yyyy}">
    <Binding Path="UserInitials" />
    <Binding Path="EntryDate" />
  </MultiBinding>
</tk:DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
```

Thanks to everyone who took the time to look.

Comment: Example from MSDN including a Converter [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

Unless you intend to have a leading space in the formatted value you should use this binding instead:

```
<tk:DataGridTextColumn.Binding> 
  <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} - {1:dd/MM/yyyy}"> 
    <Binding Path="UserInitials" />
    <Binding Path="EntryDate" />
  </MultiBinding>
</tk:DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
```

If the `StringFormat` starts with a left brace `{` the XAML parser require you to escape it using a pair of braces `{}`. Otherwise the parser gets confused because braces also are used in the syntax of markup extensions.

Details are found in the XAML documentation for [{} Escape Sequence / Markup Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744986.aspx).

Perhaps you had the escape sequence correctly placed in the format string initially and the moved things around resulting in the empty pair of braces at the wrong place?